# globalize3 - Query translated attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, globalize3

I have 2 models:

```
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :description
  belongs_to :gender 
end
```

After integrating with globalize3 I cannot figure out how to get query that joins to work, for example:
`Product.joins(:gender).where(genders: { name: 'male' })`

which generates this sql query:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
INNER JOIN "genders" ON "genders"."id" = "products"."gender_id" 
WHERE "genders"."name" = 'male'`
```

But I think I need a sql query that looks like this?

```
SELECT * FROM products 
INNER JOIN genders on genders.id = products.gender_id 
INNER JOIN gender_translations on gender_translations.gender_id = genders.id 
WHERE gender_translations.name = 'male';
```

So how does one do the rails equivalent of this sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of `Product.joins(gender: :translations).where(gender: { translations: { name: 'male' }})` should do the trick I believe.

The `joins(gender: :translations)` is a nested inner join. So you're joining `products`-> `genders`, and  `genders` -> `gender_translations`.

The `where` hash syntax is just an attempt to generate the SQL: `where("gender_translations.prompt = 'male'")`. If the hash syntax isn't correct/fights you, I'd just revert to the raw SQL just mentioned. It's arguably more clear anyways!

Comment: thank you for your reply @dleve123, but `Product.joins(gender: :translations).where(gender: { translations: { name: 'male' }})` is  exactly what I ended up doing when I asked this question, and at the end I did write raw sql in rails where method like you suggested. Perhaps I'll dig out the old error message later and we can have a look from there.